# Include lines for upper and lower limits of a legend patch in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend

Regarding legend patches in ArcGIS Pro, I have a raster and would like to add two tiny black lines at the upper and lower limit of the associated patch (see attached picture). However, I cannot find an option to do this in ArcGIS Pro. What can I do so that I don't have to work around this by creating the black lines manually for each of my maps?

[image]